# jQuery, activeadmin: custom filter with ransack. how to alter displayed text in search box

Tags: activeadmin, jquery-autocomplete

i got activeadmin (1.0.0.pre1) working with rails-jquery-autocomplete (1.0.2) [rails-4 setup].

i am able to auto-complete queries and call a search on them; however, when the search returns and the index form reloads, the search box (in sidebar panel) displays queried string wrapped in ["string"] (square braces and quotes)

e.g. if i search with `AWonderfulDay` and select an auto-completed element, the form reload results in `["AWonderfulDay"]` shown as innerText of input element (search box)

Following is the generated UI element

```
<input data-autocomplete="/comments/autocomplete_comments" id="q_comments_in" name="q[comments_in]" type="text" value="[&quot;SearchString&quot;]" class="ui-autocomplete-input" autocomplete="off">
```

The search has been implemented using ransack and the filter is:

```
  filter :comments_in, as: :autocomplete, url: '/comments/autocomplete_comments',
                          label: 'Search Comments', required: false,
                          wrapper_html: {style: "list-style: none"}
```

pointed to a trivial:

```
  ransacker :comment,
            :formatter => ->(comment) {
              data = User.joins(:profile => :comment).where("comments.comment = ?", comment).map(&:id)
              data = data.present? ? data: nil
  } do |parent|
    parent.table[:id]
  end
```

i do know this is because of `in` predicate (doesn't happen with `cont` predicate and i have that in another filter working well, e.g. `filter :comments_cont` will not cause this)

**edit 1:**

Also, https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/issues/345 shows a snapshot with same behavior.

This also led me to another question here [Custom search with ransacker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22473391/custom-search-with-ransacker)

i should have done a better job at looking up for them earlier. sorry for that!

**edit 2:**

here are my model relations:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :profile, :inverse_of => :users, :touch => true

class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :comment, dependent: :destroy

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :profile, touch: true
```

Comment: You don't use ransack in the way it works. What does `query` exactly do?

Comment: @TimoSchilling  i've updated query above with model relations i have. 
could you please also comment what's wrong with the way i am using ransack here. Thanks!

Comment: Please at all related models (only the relation related lines)

Comment: Please refer above. updated in edit-2

Comment: i got this working by following up the discussions on linked issues.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved it by correcting my use of ransack.

In models/comment.rb:

```
scope :search_comment, lambda { |x| ..}

def self.ransackable_scopes(auth_object = nil)
  [:search_comment]
end
```

In admin/profile.rb

```
filter :search_comment, as: :autocomplete, url: "controller_url",
                   label: 'Search Comment', required: false,
                   wrapper_html: {style: 'list-style: none'}
```